# Select data Only if it doesnt have a certain value inside it

Tags: sql, if-statement, select

we have a legacy case management that runs via sql thru ms access.

our table example shows like this

[image: TABLE]

is there a way to pull or select show a certain data only if it doesnt have a certain SNUM.

like we have casenum with multiple snum entry. but we only want to select casenum that never had an entry from a certain snum

so if for example there is a casenum with an entry only from 151 and 152 but no entry from 153 and 154 then it will show.

but if a casenum has an entry from snum 153 or 154 then it will not show it

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. A picture of partial data doesn't provide the data types, nor a convenient way to supply sample data for testing a query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select casenum 
from your_table
group by casenum 
having sum(case when snum in (153, 154) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
   and sum(case when snum = 151 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
   and sum(case when snum = 152 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```